# how can i get the contractor auto populated after searching 1 company from the text box

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is the code for the company i need is the next code for auto populating the contractors.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<button class="btn w100per btn-default bgColor-lb" value="@item.CompanyId" onclick="selectCompanyPOST(this)">

    <span hidden="hidden">@item.CompanyId</span>
    <span hidden="hidden">@item.EnterpriseType</span>

    <span>@item.CompanyName</span> |
    <span>@item.CompanyAddress</span> |
    <span>@item.Zone</span> |
    <span>@item.CompCode</span>
</button>
}
```

Comment: Hi Joeben. Sorry but I did not understand what do you mean.

Comment: You don't state what you want auto populated but I would suggest making an AJAX call to get the data for the company chosen